# How do I enable multiple cores in my virtual enviroment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu in a virtual enviroment using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager and it works great.

However I'd like to enable multiple cores - as seen in the image below my Windows machine has 2 cores:
[image]

Now when I run the `lscpu` in Ubunto I get the following info revealing that only 1 core is being utilized:
[image]

I've tried changing the settings of the virtual box to enable multiple processors but it won't allow me to do so as shown in the image below:
[image]

How do I enable multiple cores (processors) in my virtual enviroment?

Comment: This is not a programming related question and you would do better to seek answers at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VM is currently running (or "Saved") you can't change that value.
Apart from that several sources like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x) one suggest, that you need need to enable "VT-x" under the Acceleration tab to get this working. I couldn't reproduce that, it works for me without having VT-x enabled.

Comment: Awesome - I had the machien state as saved - I powered it off and I could change the settings - thanks!